# Appointment changed by another person notification to organizer. How to turn it off?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We are making a web based solution with Exchange appointment synchronization throw EWS. After appointment created in our system it will be imported to exchange. Aappointment changes in our system are followed by Exchange appoinment updates. This operations are made with credentials of application pool. For some instalations updates in Exchange appointment will be followed by email for organizer. This email informes orginizer about changes in his appointment that were made not by him. Other instalations don't send such a mail. We need to tell Exchange "hey! don't send notification to orginizer!". How can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

When you send the update, you need to set the `SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode` to `SendtoNone`:

```
ewsAppt.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToNone);
```